# Storing double value, issue on restoring in another computer because of different user region?

Tags: c#, serialization, double

I'm using binary formatter to store an object, this object contains some double fields. after saving the object in a file, when i open it in another windows using the same app but with different windows region config, the app fails to open the file because it can't parse the double fields.
i'm storing the double values in string variables because i need the user to be free saving the file any time without validation, i validate the values in another step.
my question is how can i make sure my file opens in any windows even if the decimal character is defined different?
here is a screenshot of the decimal character i mean in case i couldn't define it good.

[image: decimal character config]

Comment: A double is a 4 byte floating number.  So store it as four bytes not as a string.  You have a binary file so you don't need to make the data readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Culture.InvariantCulture` when saving and restoring the `double` values.
This guarantees the same storage format no matter what locale the user selected.

I can't give exact code, because it depends on how you actually convert the values to `double` and you didn't show that in your question.

Comment: @RezaMansouri I already explained in my answer that I can't show you how, because you failed to show the code you use for storing and reading.

Comment: I'm using double.Parse

Comment: That's only half the story. How do you convert the double to string? Oh, and please, try solving your own problems. Google: double parse Culture.InvariantCulture. I am not telling you this because I am mean, but I am trying to teach you to become a better developer that is capable of performing such basic research themselves.

Comment: lets say I do double.parse("3.14"), in some machines it needs double.parse("3/14") to parse it.

Comment: So use the same method with different overload :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MajkeloDev That's correct. But I wanted the OP to find this out by himself.